# How can I change bar graph y axis to represent their value?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking to plot just the percent of measurements that fall within bands. I have them separated into low med and high. But when I plot them, it will show not show values representatively (See image for example output)

Code Below

```
percents <- data.frame(TI = c("Low","Med","High"),
                   percent = c(format((totallowcount/totalvaluescount)*100,digits=3),
                             format((totalmedcount/totalvaluescount)*100,digits=3),
                             format((totalhighcount/totalvaluescount)*100,digits=3)))

TIbarplot <- ggplot(data = percents, aes(x = TI, y = percent)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Low","Med","High"))
```

Output[image: Bar graph].

I looked into doing scale_y_discrete `scale_y_discrete(limits=c(0,25,50,100))` but kept getting errors for it.

`Error in matrix(value, n, p) : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
In addition: Warning message:
Removed 3 rows containing missing values
(position_stack).`

Comment: The problem is that `format` is converting your values into strings. For example, run `class(format(1.1234, digits  = 1))`. The data frame then calls them factors. If you want to round to three digits, use `round` instead of `format`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is that by formatting the `percents$percent` column, you are saving these as factors

```
> class(percents$percent)
[1] "factor"
```

A quick `dplyr::mutate` can change the class for `ggplot`

```
library(dplyr)
percents %>% 
  mutate(percent = as.numeric(as.character(percent))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = TI, y = percent)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Low","Med","High"))
```

However, I'd recommend that you don't change the formatting in your dataframe, and leave the formatting to `ggplot` functionality:

```
percents <- data.frame(TI = c("Low","Med","High"),
                       percent = c(totallowcount/totalvaluescount,
                                   totalmedcount/totalvaluescount,
                                   totalhighcount/totalvaluescount))

ggplot(data = percents, aes(x = TI, y = percent)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Low","Med","High")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```